# Fatal error: Class 'mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf' not found

Tags: php, composer

Não tenho muita familiaridade com o composer e preciso usar a biblioteca `phpwkhtmltopdf`.

Uso o Windows 8.1. Fiz a instalação pelo setup normal, e parece que ele está funcionando normalmente:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fiz a instalação utilizando o comando

```
composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf
```

E, no código do meu site, chamei a biblioteca:

```
use mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf;
```

Porém, sempre dá o erro:

```
Fatal error: Class 'mikehaertl\wkhtmlto\Pdf' not found in...
```

Acho que preciso chamar o composer de alguma forma no código. Mas, segundo a documentação da biblioteca e o manual de instalação do composer, isso deveria funcionar. O que está faltando?

Answer (score 2):

Descobri. Eu tenho que dar o comando `composer require mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf` dentro da pasta do meu projeto e adicionar a linha `require '/vendor/autoload.php';`antes de chamar a classe.